# Function definition and Source ordering of tcl files

Tags: tcl

I have multiple tcl files getting sourced

```
     source fg_lib.tcl
     source stc_lib.tcl
```

In stc_lib.tcl, there is a function which is only defined in fg_lib.tcl. Can I assume that since fg_lib.tcl is getting sourced, automatically the function will be usable to stc_lib.tcl?

One more question: if a certain function is defined in both the tcl files, depending on the ordering of source as above, which version of the function will be executed? I think function defined in stc_lib.tcl will be, but still would like to clarify.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The `source` command acts, immediately, as if the content of the file was in the script at the point where the `source` appears (except for the difference of what `info script` returns). If both scripts define a procedure `foobar`, it will be the later script (`stc_lib.tcl` in your case) that produces the version that is used.

However, if the scripts just define procedures that don't have overlapping names and don't otherwise call the commands they create, the order in which the `source`s are placed is typically unimportant. The `proc` command just creates a command; the body of the procedure isn't evaluated until the procedure is called. (This sounds obvious, but it really is exactly like that. The code is exactly what it says it is, and Tcl is all about immediate operational semantics and code that is registered to be run in response to some event.)

Bear in mind that if you are having problems with `source`s smashing each other, it's probably best to look into putting the code into namespaces or to otherwise find a way to stop entangling things. Writing confusing code is not recommended.

Comment: Since stc_lib.tcl is dependent on fg_lib.tcl, it should source fg_lib.tcl.  Of course, since you don't want to be sourceing files twice, you should look into `package provide` and `package require`.    As the project gets larger, you don't want to be trying to remember in which order the files need to get sourced.